# New to Solidity and need to deploy a token

Tags: solidity

First time here. I would like to create a BEP20 token. I don't have experience with Solidity, that's why I used a tool https://cointool.app/ to generate token code.

The code is here: https://pastebin.com/ASrNehCE

First of all there is a problem on line 91. The `return msg.sender` is showing the error below:

```
Return argument type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) address payable.
```

Code:

```
 abstract contract Context {
      function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address payable) {
          return msg.sender;
      }

      function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes memory) {
          this; // silence state mutability warning without generating bytecode - see https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2691
          return msg.data;
      }
  }
```

I would also like to know if this is production ready and safe to use for a real live token. If not, can anybody suggest any improvements?

Comment: The link to the code doesn't work, it is a link to an old version of remix.ethereum.org. With solc v0.8 msg.sender has to be casted to payable, `payable(msg.sender)`, see https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/080-breaking-changes.html for other changes.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for that. Where can I host this code so I can share it?

Comment: Just be aware that longer code means less people will want to read it. Try to create a small reproducible example. Having said that you can use a github.com repo to host the code.

Comment: I understand ... but this is the code that I have from CoinTool ... there's no way to create a smaller example since it will all be used.

Comment: I got it up here: https://pastebin.com/ASrNehCE. Didn't change anything in it. Exactly what CoinTool generates.